# Still being Prompt for Password After enabling Public Keys

Tags: server, ssh, sshd, two-factor-authentication

When I added my public key into my .ssh/user/authorized_keys file and I saved and restarted my server it gave me this error:

```
initctl: Unable to connect to system bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
* Restarting OpenBSD Secure Shell server sshd
start-stop-daemon: warning: failed to kill 477: Operation not permitted
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
```

I'm not really sure what I did wrong, I have my public key in that folder (double checked) and I also do have it in my own windows 10 computer. Was I suppose to generate the public and private key on the terminal or on my own computer? I also used git bash to to generate it because normal window's terminal would not work. 
I also think that my home directory is encrypted because when I typed in the command:

```
df $HOME
```

part of it displayed `/vz/private/` if that helps. My `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file is fine too, it has this:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/%u/authorized_keys
```

I have been working on this for a few hours already, if anyone also knows a good tutorial on ubuntu please give a link because I have been struggling trying to make my server as secure as possible for the past week.

UPDATE:
I have tried to remove and regenerate the host key using this site https://www.digitalocean.com/company/blog/avoid-duplicate-ssh-host-keys/ but when I do service ssh restart I still get the error above except instead of:

```
    start-stop-daemon: warning: failed to kill 477: Operation not permitted
```

I get instead:

```
    start-stop-daemon: warning: failed to kill 1015: Operation not permitted
```

Incase if it helps, I still am being prompted for a password and it does display a warning that there was a new key generated when I log onto a new putty secession. 
EDIT:1
Ok so I found out what as wrong, I was not using sudo when I did service ssh restart, however I am still not prompt for public key authentication when I log in..

Comment: Ok so I found out what as wrong, I was not using sudo when I did service ssh restart, however I am still not prompt for public key authentication when I log in...

Answer (score 0):

Served does not have the host keys. You need to create them, preferably using

```
dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server
```

Comment: ? I thought you were suppose to create them on the client... this is what I'm using. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys

Comment: They are called "host keys" for a reason.

Comment: I did ssh-keygen on my computer which generate the id_rsa and id_rsa.pub and then I pasted the public key into the authorized key file... isn't that right? Sorry if I'm wrong

Comment: It is ok for client authentication keys. But you also need the others ^^

Comment: Well digital ocean and ubuntu wiki didn't do a very good job in explaining it.. or I am just a bad reader

Comment: Ok, so basically I also need public and private keys on my remote server too.. but I thought that the server used MY client public key to authenticate. Incase your wondering I only have 1 user on the host of that helps.. sorry I'm not really understanding this

Comment: It is not described well on the linked page. But you might check [this one on DO](https://www.digitalocean.com/company/blog/avoid-duplicate-ssh-host-keys/) describing the procedure. Normally you should not need to care about this and it should be generated after installation. But for some reason it was not in your case.

Comment: I found out that the reason why service ssh restart wasn't working was because I wasn't using sudo permissions but I still get prompt up for a password instead of a key..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38789/discussion-between-johnnyinno1-and-jakuje).